# Is a collection of open sets is a basis for a topology on $X$ if it gives a basis for a dense subset of $X$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $Y$ be a dense subset of a topological space $X$. Let $\mathcal B := \{U_\alpha : \alpha \in \Lambda\}$ be a collection of open subsets of $X$ such that $\{U_\alpha\cap Y : \alpha \in \Lambda\}$ is a basis for the subspace topology on $Y$. Is it true that $\mathcal B$ is a basis for the topology on $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another example. Consider $X = \mathbb{R}$ equipped with the usual topology and $Y = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ (which is clearly dense in $X$). Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the set of all open sets not containing $0$. Then $\mathcal{B}$ is already a basis for $Y$ (indeed, it contains *all* open subsets of $Y$ in the subspace topology) but isn't a basis for $X$ since it does not contain any open neighborhood of $0$.

Answer (score 2):

No. Suppose $X$ with $x \in X$ has the topology where a set is open if and only if it is empty or contains $x$. Then the set $\{x\}$ is dense (since the only closed set containing it is $X$), and $\{X\}$ is a collection of open subsets of $X$ such that $\{X \cap \{x\}\} = \{\{x\}\}$ is a bsis for the subspace topology on $\{x\}$. Yet clearly $\{X\}$ is not a basis for the topology on $X$.